# Python multiprocessing apply_async + Value

Tags: python, multiprocessing, counter, shared

I try to pass shared counter to tasks in multiprocessing by apply_async but it fails with such error "RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance". What's going on

```
def processLine(lines, counter, mutex):
    pass

counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
mutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
pool = Pool(processes = 8)
lines = []

for line in inputStream:
    lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) >= 5000:
         #don't queue more than 1'000'000 lines
         while counter.value > 1000000:
                 time.sleep(0.05)
         mutex.acquire()
         counter.value += len(lines)
         mutex.release()
         pool.apply_async(processLine, args=(lines, counter, ), callback = collectResults)
         lines = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the pool handle the scheduling:

```
for result in pool.imap(process_single_line, input_stream):
    pass
```

If order doesn't matter:

```
for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_single_line, input_stream):
    pass
```

`pool.*map*()` function have `chunksize` argument that you can change to see whether it affects performance in your case.

If your code expects multiple lines to be passed in a single call:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

chunks = izip_longest(*[iter(inputStream)]*5000, fillvalue='') # grouper recipe
for result in pool.imap(process_lines, chunks):
    pass
```

Some alternatives to limit number of queued items are:

- `multiprocessing.Queue` with set max size (you don't need a pool in this case). `queue.put()` will block when the max size is reached until other processes call `queue.get()`
- manual implementation of producer/consumer pattern using multiprocessing primitives such as Condition or BoundedSemaphor.

Note: each Value has associated lock, you don't need a separate lock.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in such not elegant way

```
def processLine(lines):
    pass

def collectResults(result):
    global counter
    counter -= len(result)

counter = 0
pool = Pool(processes = 8)
lines = []

for line in inputStream:
    lines.append(line)
    if len(lines) >= 5000:
         #don't queue more than 1'000'000 lines
         while counter.value > 1000000:
             time.sleep(0.05)
         counter.value += len(lines)
         pool.apply_async(processLine, args=(lines), callback = collectResults)
         lines = []
```

Comment: I understand that this is some minimal snippet, but I'm worried that your callback function is not doing what you expect. Since `processLine` has no return value, you really shouldn't be calling `len(result)` as it has no meaning. If you are going to answer your own question you should keep it fully self-contained.